# CSS Dropdown Menu Items not Aligning

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Im having issues with my dropdown menu. I added a padding in my Ul line so my menu would align in the center, but after that the dropdown items will not align. I'm sure the problem is in my CSS, but i will include both HTML and CSS. Ive been told some of this code is redundant, but for this problem I would like to leave it like it is.

```css
body {
  background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/39811/pexels-photo-39811.jpeg') no-repeat;
  Background-size: cover;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
}
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:70px;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: in-line;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<htlm>
  <link href='style2.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>About Me</a></li>
        <li><a>About My Project</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    <li><a>News</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Tech News</a></li>
        <li><a>World News</a></li>
        <li><a>Science News</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Lessons</a></li>
  </ul>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say 'align', how *exactly* do you want the dropdowns to appear? 'News' and 'About' both have dropdowns that appear at the same offset. Do you want the sub-menu to appear *below* the main menu?
 Also, you have two tags (`<htlm>` and `</le>`) that are typos. It may be worth validating your markup with the [**W3 Markup Validator**](https://validator.w3.org/) service.

Comment: yes I would like the sub menu to appear below the main menu. Could you explain how they are typos? I followed a tutorial on youtube, and I was wanting to expand on what he did.

Comment: The tags should be `<html>` and `</li>` respectively. The `<html>` denotes that the file is an HTML document, and you already have the corresponding `</html>` tag at the end. Most of your list items are closed with `</li>` (ending the list item), though one is closed with `</le>` (resulting in invalid syntax, and unexpected display).

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. the typo was just a matter of not paying attention. thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

You didn't reset **-webkit-padding-start** for second ul.

You can find more here: http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-padding-start

HTML

```css
body {
  background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/39811/pexels-photo-39811.jpeg') no-repeat;
  Background-size: cover;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: in-line;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul {
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  -moz-padding-start: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul li a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>About Me</a></li>
            <li><a>About My Project</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    <li><a>News</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Tech News</a></li>
            <li><a>World News</a></li>
            <li><a>Science News</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Lessons</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that didnt seem to fix it.

Comment: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjYJXr](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjYJXr) Added code to codepen, can you explain what don't work properly in there or send an screenshot?

Comment: okay, i guess i didnt add something from your previous comment. I copied and pasted everything and it worked. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
         body {
    background: #eee;
    Background-size: cover;
    font-family: arial;
    color: white;
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 60px;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    opacity: 0.8;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: in-line;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul li:hover .subnav {
    display: block;
}
.subnav li {
    float: none;
            position: relative;
}
.subnav {
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
    -moz-padding-start: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.subnav li a {
    display: block;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a>About Me</a></le>
            <li><a>About My Project</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    <li><a>News</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a>Tech News</a></li>
            <li><a>World News</a></li>
            <li><a>Science News</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Lessons</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```